# How to write ... after 5 characters

Tags: php, html, css

I'm beginner and I have a question. I would like that if my text is more than 5 characters, that it writes 5 characters + ... . It's for shortening a name in navbar if its too long, it causes bugs in my nav.

Here's an example of desired result:

My text: `TheTest`

output: `TheTe...`

I think I could do this with `strlen()` but have no idea how to do this. Maybe with an `overflow` ?

I tried to do it with `text-overflow: ellipsis;` but it didn't work either
Can you help me please ?

Comment: You can watch this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_yK6KFxNww @BaguetteV1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just check the length to see if its more than 5 character or not

```
$mesage="This is text String";

if(strlen($mesage)>5){

    echo substr($mesage,0,5)."...";
}
else{

    echo $mesage;
}
```

More infos about `strlen():` http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strlen.php 
                        
 `substr():`           https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php